# How to get update object with webhook in C#?

Tags: c#, webhooks, telegram

I use C# for programming Telegram Bot, but when I set webhook I can't fill Update object? I use ashx handler.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        Fwk_Log.Insert("before","before");
        var update = context.Request.QueryString["Update"];
        Fwk_Log.Insert(update, "update = ");
        long offset = 0;
        int whilecount = 0;
        int updateId = 0;
        whilecount += 1;
        string updates = Fwk_HttpRequest.ExecuteUrlRequestJSONString("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + Token + "/getUpdates");
        Shp_Telegram_GetUpdate list = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Shp_Telegram_GetUpdate>(updates);
        if (list != null)
        {
            foreach (var r in list.result)
            {
                //offset = list.result.First().update_id;
                if (r.message.text == "/start")
                {
                    Fwk_HttpRequest.ExecuteUrlRequestJSONString("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + Token +
                        "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + r.message.chat.id + "&text=" + "Hello World");
                    Fwk_Log.Insert("sendMessage", "");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting things mixed up. See [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getting-updates)

> There are two mutually exclusive ways of receiving updates for your
>   bot — the getUpdates method on one hand and Webhooks on the other.
>   Incoming updates are stored on the server until the bot receives them
>   either way, but they will not be kept longer than 24 hours.
>
> Regardless of which option you choose, you will receive
>   JSON-serialized Update objects as a result.

If you are using **webhooks**, you do not need to call **`getUpdate`** method.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I set the my service on webhook and got my telegram robot is successfully set up. Now if anyone  sent  a message to the Bot is given to the service but do not know how to fill Update object?  @charles-okwuagwu
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            Fwk_Log.Insert("before","before");
            var update = context.Request.QueryString["Update"];
            Fwk_Log.Insert(update, "update = ");

            context.Response.Write("my service");
        }

Comment: @milad so you can receive updates, all you need is a way to process them, right?

Comment: yes i need a way to process this. just i want how to fill Update Object? i use ashx handeller in ASP

Comment: @milad when you receive an incoming update, try to read the entire context.request and parse it as json. Remove this line: `string updates = Fwk_HttpRequest.ExecuteUrlRequestJSONString(...`

Comment: @milad what was the solution

Comment: I could not get Update object as json. i try below code to get this:
 string json = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();